# nested dictionary returns set()?

Tags: python, dictionary, sqlalchemy

I am working on dynamically creating a dictionary from a database table. The `hosts_list` is a list of hostnames that I have selected from the `host_names` column in the `hosts` table. Once I have the list of hostnames, I create a dictionary with each hostname as the key, initialised with an empty value. The values in hosts_dict are set via nested dictionary comprehension of the same table.

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/cm', convert_unicode=True)
metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
db = engine.connect()
hosts = Table('hosts', metadata, autoload=True)
results = db.execute(select({hosts}))

hosts_list =[]
for x in results:
    hosts_list.append(x[hosts.c.host_name])

hosts_dict = dict.fromkeys(hosts_list)
for key, value in hosts_dict.items():
    hosts_dict[key] = {
    {column : value for column,value in x.items()} 
    for x in results}
```

Here is the test data I've been using (formatted for readability):

Colums: `hosts_id,host_uuid,host_name,host_ip,host_os,host_active`

Row: `4; "35968946-2db0-4f85-b764-14c27ab3a57c";"test-04";"192.168.1.4";"RHEL 6.x";FALSE`

Here is what my end goal is (formatted for readability):

```
{
    'test-01': {
        'hosts_id':'1',
        'host_uuid':'a5c52229-34e5-4f54-a7da-b39149dedc13',
        'host_name':'test-01',
        'host_os':'Ubuntu 14.04',
        'host_active':'True'},
    'test-04': {
        'hosts_id':'4'
        'host_uuid':'35968946-2db0-4f85-b764-14c27ab3a57c'
        'host_name':'test-04'
        'host_ip':'192.168.1.4'
        'host_os':'RHEL 6.6'
        'host_active':'False'},
    'test-03': {...},
    'test-02': {...}
}
```

Here are the results I'm actually getting:

```
print(hosts_dict)
{'test-01': set(), 'test-04': set(), 'test-03': set(), 'test-02': set()}
```

I'm not sure what that means. I read the documentation on [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-set), but I don't quite understand it. With `[[print("'{0}':'{1}'".format(column,value)) for column, value in v.items()] for v in results]` I can get a print of the column and it's value in each row like this:

```
'hosts_id':'1'
'host_uuid':'a5c52229-34e5-4f54-a7da-b39149dedc13'
'host_name':'test-01'
'host_ip':'192.168.1.1'
'host_os':'Ubuntu 14.04'
'host_active':'True'
...
```

How can I go from what I have to what my end goal is?

Comment: Don't [cross-post](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/287881/110531). Also your question is unclear; what don't you understand about `set`? Note that a set comprehension `{x for x in y}` looks a lot like a dictionary comprehension `{x: y for x, y in z}`...

Comment: This post is about how to solve the problems and the other post is asking what `set()` actually is because I don't understand it.

Comment: Well your first problem is that that's *not at all clear*. That's an awful lot of question on Programmers for *"what is a `set`?"*, and yet doesn't explain what you've read, what you've learned and what you still want to know. Meanwhile this question is a long way from a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please read [ask] for both sites and clarify your precise issues.

Comment: As I [already stated](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/287881/set-is-the-value-in-a-keyvalue-pair#comment594474_287881): Please edit your question and provide a snippet of results since this seems to be the entry point for further investigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/cm', convert_unicode=True)
metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
db = engine.connect()
hosts = Table('hosts', metadata, autoload=True)
results = db.execute(select({hosts}))

hosts_dict = {}
for x in results:
    host_name = x[hosts.c.host_name]
    hosts_dict[host_name] = {column: value for column, value in x.items()}
```

Comment: I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

```
hosts_dict[key] = {
    {column : value for column,value in x.items()} 
    for x in results}
```

Is a set comprehension (`{item for ...}`), not a dictionary comprehension (`{key: value for ...}`).

```
hosts_dict.update({
    key: {column : value for column,value in x.items()} 
    for x in results})
```

Is a dictionary comprehension. But then, the order of a dictionary's keys is undefined, so the assumption `key` matches `x` because they were both derived from `results` in the same order is wrong.

```
hosts_dict = {x[hosts.c.host_name]: {column: value for column, value in x.items()}
              for x in results}
```

Is probably what you want. Or even,

```
hosts_dict = {x[hosts.c.host_name]: x.items() for x in results}
```

Comment: Ah! That explains it. I only vaguely understand set/dictionary to begin with, so that would explain where I went wrong. Thanks for the explanation!